# How to give a struct array field a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, go, grpc, go-gorm, grpc-go

This question have a number of of layer and I'll try to explain it as best as I can.

So the start is with `gRPC`. I have this snippet on my protobuf:

```
message User {
    string id = 1;
    string first_name = 2;
    string last_name = 3;
    string user_name = 4;
    string password = 5;
    repeated EdgeDevice owned_edge_devices = 6;
}

enum EdgeDeviceStatus {
    UNREACHABLE = 0;
    ACTIVE = 1;
}
  
 message EdgeDevice {
    string id = 1;
    EdgeDeviceStatus status = 2;
}
```

That I translated as the structs below:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID               string `gorm:"primarykey"`
    FirstName        string
    LastName         string
    UserName         string
    Password         string
    OwnedEdgeDevices []EdgeDevice `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
    CreatedAt        time.Time    `gorm:"autoCreateTime:false"`
    UpdatedAt        time.Time    `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:false"`
}

type EdgeDevice struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID        string `gorm:"primarykey"`
    Status    int32
    CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime:false"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:false"`
}
```

I'm not quite sure if I converted the `protobuf` messages as close as possible to a `struct`, but that's not the biggest issue right now I think. Right now, I can't figure out how to make gorm accept the structs without having to make Valuer/Scanner interface. The ways I found to give `OwnedEdgeDevices` a foreign key doesn't seem to work. I already tried the samples on [gorm's Has Many documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Has-Many). Most of them gives me the error:

> Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key
> constraint 'fk_users_owned_edge_devices' are incompatible.

One reason I think that was causing all this issues is that I'm using a string primary key as I want to use uuid for my ids, for security purposes.

So my questions are:

1. For first I guess, did I convert the protobuf to struct just right?
2. How do I give `OwnedEdgeDevices` a foreign key?
3. Then lastly, is a Valuer/Scanner interface the only way for me to make this work

Taking @LeGEC's suggestion into consideration, I made all the things needed to handle a many-to-many relation between `User` and `EdgeDevice` and called them `EdgeDeviceOwnership`. It's struct looks like:

```
type EdgeDeviceOwnership struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID           string     `gorm:"primarykey"`
    UserID       string     `gorm:"size:40; index; not null"`
    User         User       `gorm:"foreignKey:UserID; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    EdgeDeviceID string     `gorm:"size:40; index; not null"`
    EdgeDevice   EdgeDevice `gorm:"foreignKey:EdgeDeviceID; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time  `gorm:"autoCreateTime:false"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time  `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:false"`
}
```

Which I thought should work flawlessly, but I'm still getting the similar error from before. The "Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'fk_edge_device_ownerships_user' are incompatible.". The only change I made on `User` is removing `OwnedEdgeDevices`. Could this still be because of my string primary key?

Comment: What should be the foreign key in the fields of `EdgeDevice` ? Regarding SQL schema : you can either add an extra `UserID` column in `EdgeDevice` (if relation is many-to-one: a device belongs to at most one user) or add a relation table (if relation is many-to-many)

Comment: I did try adding `UserID` inside `EdgeDevice`, but it didn't work. Adding that gives me " Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'fk_users_owned_edge_devices' are incompatible."

Comment: Having an intermediary table for the relation might be a good option

Answer (score 0):

I kinda cheated a bit as I asked our "smart friend" for this answer which gave me an idea for a fix.

So it told me that for string foreign key's, the length of them should match. That the `ID` of the table's involved should have the same length. Even though the error kept saying that it's got an issue with user's `ID` not being the same as the generated foreign key for it, it seems like it was already evaluating the edgedevice's `ID` as well for some reason, because I already have the `size` tag on user's `ID` and it was still complaining about user. So I added a `size` tag for the primary keys of each table and it fixed the issue. The structs look like this now.

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID        string `gorm:"primarykey; size:40;"`
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    UserName  string
    Password  string
    CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime:false"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:false"`
}

type EdgeDevice struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID        string `gorm:"primarykey; size:40;"`
    Status    int32
    CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"autoCreateTime:false"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:false"`
}

type EdgeDeviceOwnership struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID           string     `gorm:"primarykey; size:40;"`
    UserID       string     `gorm:"size:40; index; not null"`
    User         User       `gorm:"foreignKey:UserID; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    EdgeDeviceID string     `gorm:"size:40; index; not null"`
    EdgeDevice   EdgeDevice `gorm:"foreignKey:EdgeDeviceID; constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time  `gorm:"autoCreateTime:false"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time  `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:false"`
}
```